# How to install a skin ( from Samsung ) for android emulator with "ADT 21.0.1" in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, adt, eclipse-adt

How to install a skin ( from Samsung ) for android emulator with "ADT 21.0.1" in eclipse ?

i can do it with "ADT 16.0.1", i have used a Skin of Galaxy S2 from Samsung
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-S2-Skin-for-handset-emulation

Comment: I'm curious for this one too, I tried a lot but nothing doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Unzip the skin folder and Just copy it to /platforms/android-x/skins/. Then restart eclipse and you can see Galaxy S2 skin while creating a new emulator.