# How to set a skin on a newly created avd using android-emulator 26.1.0.0

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Reading through the documentation over [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#deprecated) regarding the `emulator` command line tool (now released separately since Android SDK 26.0.0), you can see the deprecated list of flags. One of them is `-skin`, but I cannot find any alternative to it.

I want to assign skins to my emulators created on a remote CI server with no display, but I want to ensure that the orientation and the display resolution is properly set, and from my testing I could only get that right when settings `-skin` flag to a given configuration.

Any tips of how to replace `-skin` flag or to achieve the same results without it?

Here's the version of the emulator I am running:

```
Android emulator version 26.1.0.0 (build_id 4010741)
```

Here's the command I use to create the avd:

```
avdmanager --verbose create avd --force \
                                --name "Nexus72012" \
                                --package "system-images;android-19;google_apis;x86" \
                                --sdcard 1000M \
                                --device 13
```

And this is how I start up the avd:

```
emulator @Nexus72012 -wipe-data -verbose -logcat '*:e *:w' -netfast -no-boot-anim -no-audio -no-window
```

**Please note, I am limited to command line solutions, therefore please keep your answers targeted at that**

Comment: right now resolution is ignored from `--device 13` param =( so I continue to use `emulator -skin 480x800` on top

Answer (score 1):

I am on the same issue. But I got to set a galaxy skin not using the GUI. Here is the logic:

###### For the first time

1. Choose a directory to create an 'skins' folder in.
2. Now download the skin and unzip it into 'skins' folder.
3. Run `emulator @Tester -skindir <dir> -skin <name>`

That will run the created AVD named 'Tester' in the skin named *<name>* that will be search for inside *<dir>*.

> use '-skin ' to specify an emulator skin, each skin corresponds to
> the visual appearance of a given device, including buttons and keyboards,
> and is stored as subdirectory  of the skin root directory
> (see '-help-skindir')
>
> note that  can also be 'x' (e.g. '320x480') to
> specify an exact framebuffer size, without any visual ornaments.

> use '-skindir ' to specify a directory that will be used to search
> for emulator skins. each skin must be a subdirectory of . by default
> the emulator will look in the 'skins' sub-directory of the system directory

###### If not the first time

1. Just download the skin (if not already) and unzip it into 'skins' folder.
2. Run `emulator @Tester -skindir <dir> -skin <name>`

You can use other options in additional to this. BTW, I got a galaxy skin from [here](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/guide.html).

also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22746469/15185574).